# Need pattern for typescript when use useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html5-canvas

```
const CanvasMap = () => {
      const canvasFef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
      useEffect(() => {
        canvasFef && canvasFef.current && cities.forEach(function (item) {
             // logic here
        })
      }, [canvasFef]);
      return (
          <canvas id="canvas"
                  ref={canvasFef}
          ></canvas>
      )
    };
```

I got error

> Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'
>
> TS2322: Type 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to
> type 'LegacyRef'.   Type
> 'MutableRefObject' is not assignable to type
> 'RefObject'.
> Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
> Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLCanvasElement': captureStream, getContext, toBlob, toDataURL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const canvasFef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
```

Try this.